# How to switch app.js to app2.js running on node server?

Tags: node.js, express

I am running app.js on node server. Since the site requires login, i want to host just 1 app.get('/') on app.js.

Upon successful log-in by user, i want to swap the file app.js to app2.js which will now include more app2.get('/home'), app2.get('/otherfeature') etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you're using Express) You can create some middleware that checks if the user is authenticated. If they are, it forwards the request; otherwise, it does whatever it needs. See [`app.use` in the documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) for more information.

It turns out that if you want to apply middleware to specific routes, you can; just pass the middleware as additional arguments after the path and before the main handler.

Comment: I am using express. In middleware i will have to screen every request from user. I have more than 1 type of user which will have very different functionality. If i could swap the server file, or simply make different app.get('x,y,z') available to different users by switching the file. It would be great. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: any resources i can refer to on handlers?

Comment: @Sangram: The documentation's got information about it scattered around. I'd recommend reading through it; it's not all that long.